# Why "in der Totalen" and not "in der Totale"?

Tags: grammaticality, inflection

Reading about [*Einstellungsgröße*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstellungsgr%C3%B6%C3%9Fe), there are phrases like "In der Halbtotalen ist die Körpersprache (…)" and "In der Supertotalen (…) ist eine Landschaft der Bildinhalt."

I presume *Halbtotalen*/*Supertotalen* are in the dative, but how come is it then not "In der Totale" or "In den Totalen", as [given in Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Totale)?

Answer (score 4):

Üblicherweise wird *[die Totale](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/totale:N:F)* mit bestimmtem Artikel - wie vom Duden korrekt dargestellt - wie folgt dekliniert:

```
           Singular    Plural
Nominativ  die Totale  die Totalen  
Akkusativ  die Totale  die Totalen  
Dativ      der Totale  den Totalen  
Genitiv    der Totale  der Totalen
```

Das belegen auch diverse [Zitate aus dem Textkorpus des DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Totale):

> - Sie können Pumps in Nahaufnahme zeigen, in denen – **in der Totale** – plötzlich ein Mann steckt. <sup>Die Zeit, 24.04.2015, Nr. 17</sup>
> - Es ist, als würde man ein Fußballspiel entweder **aus der** entfernten **Totale** des Stadiondachs sehen oder stets nur ein und denselben Spieler beobachten – und solle dann eine sinnvolle Einschätzung des Spieles abgeben. <sup>Die Zeit, 25.08.2011, Nr. 35</sup>
> - Der Aufmacher: Trümmer eines Flugzeugwracks **in der Totale**. <sup>Der Tagesspiegel, 26.06.2003</sup>

Es geht aber im selben Textkorpus und mitunter bei den gleichen Zeitungen auch anders:

> - Wenn man die Szene **in der Totalen** verfolgt, sieht man auch, dass Balitsch zu diesem Zeitpunkt mindestens zehn Meter von mir entfernt war. <sup>Die Zeit, 29.08.2011</sup>

Deshalb ist mittlerweile auch die Deklination mit einem schließenden **n** im Dativ, analog zu *die Horizontale* oder *die Vertikale*, zulässig.

Answer (score 3):

I think the confusion in this Question comes from two different words, which are written and spoken the same way.

What Takkat is describing is a word that is a nominisation of "total" meaning "komplett" or "vollständig".

While "Totale" in respect to photography stems from this, it is its own word and is therefore conjugated differently.

Because of this "In der Totalen..." is correct.

The people writing the "[Zitate](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Totale)" probably made the same mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The entry in Duden is wrong.

The declination of »die Totale« is exactly the same as of »die Horizontale« or »die Vertikale«. The declination class to which these words belong is called »adjektivische Deklination«, and all words that are declined by this scheme are nominalized adjectives.

This declination class is complicated, because it depends on the kind of determiner you use together with this noun.

You can find this scheme [here, in Wiktionary, where it is shown for the word » Vertikale«](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Vertikale) (unfortunately, Wiktionary has no entry for »Totale«). You can compare it with the entry in [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Vertikale), and will see, that Duden shows for this word the same wrong declination that it shows for »Totale«.

Comment: Nein, der Duden hat nur selten unrecht.

Comment: Ich sehe keinen guten Grund, *die Totale* anders zu deklinieren als *die Sandale* (-), aber einen sehr guten, *die Totale* anders zu deklinieren als *den Vandalen* (-en).

Comment: Zumindestens Cannoo und Duden sind sich hier einig. Wiktionary hat schon zwei Wörterbücher gegen sich. Obwohl das natürlich kein Mehrheitsenscheid ist...

Comment: @tofro: bei Wiktionary fehlt witzigerweise ein Eintrag über die Totale, es kann also nicht als Beleg herhalten.

Comment: Wir hatten hier, wenn ich mich recht erinnere, auch mal was zu *Gerade*.

Comment: @tofro: Ich sehe sehr wohl einen sehr guten Grund, *Totale* und *Sandale* unterschiedlich zu deklinieren: *Totale* ist ein substantiviertes Adjektiv, *Sandale* ist ein "echtes" Nomen ("echt" im Sinn von: nicht durch Substantivierung entstanden). Ich würde aber ohnehin den tatsächlichen Sprachgebrauch über Einträge in Wörterbüchern stellen. Der Fragesteller (ParGraa) hat ja ganz richtig beobachtet, dass man »in der Totale**n**« sagt. (»Sergio Leone filmte seine Darsteller gerne in der Totale**n**.«)

Comment: @CarsteS: Die Gerade ist ebenfalls ein substantiviertes Adjektiv, und wird gleich dekliniert wie die Totale oder die Vertikale: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gerade

Comment: *in der Totalen* **kann** man ja auch sagen (siehe Takkats gute Antwort). Allerdings halte ich deine Behauptung, *in der Totale* sei falsch - für falsch.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, nicht unbedingt, daher mein Kommentar.

Comment: Zu der Geraden hatte ich geantwortet, das wusste ich nicht mehr: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9635/3237